# Regression error in R

Tags: r, regression

I was trying to use caret packages for doing feautre selection and this is comands I used:

```
    titanicDF3 = read.table("combo.txt", header = TRUE)
    View(titanicDF3)
    require(caret)
require(fscaret)
    splitIndex <- createDataPartition(titanicDF3$Survived, p = .75, list = FALSE, times = 1)
    trainDF <- titanicDF3[ splitIndex,]
    testDF  <- titanicDF3[-splitIndex,]

    fsModels <- c("glm", "gbm", "treebag", "ridge", "lasso")
    myFS<-fscaret(trainDF, testDF, myTimeLimit = 40, preprocessData=TRUE,
                  Used.funcRegPred = 'gbm', with.labels=TRUE,
                  supress.output=FALSE, no.cores=2)
```

However I was getting error:

```
Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) : 
  one node produced an error: incorrect number of dimensions
```

Since I am new to R ,I am not sure what led to this. Any idea or suggestons will be welcome.

for reference, My text file looks like this

```
Gene    Start   end Item1   Item2   Item3   Item4   Item5   Survived
100 1   56  3123    2149    3211    5000    300 0
100 34  78  3456    2345    1210    5462    321 0
100 43  98  4312    3210    2894    5487    350 0
100 54  102 4671    4310    3106    6579    390 0
100 98  121 5601    4450    4123    6792    352 0
140 130 280 7699    8790    8791    2122    768 1
140 160 321 6590    7680    8612    1278    779 1
140 210 345 8680    6712    7689    3128    987 1
140 260 431 8981    7781    9761    2199    453 1
140 324 540 9791    9941    8634    2679    410 1
```

Also I tried to use different models.    When I used glm model ,I am getting new kind of error

```
fsModels <- c("glm", "knn", "svmPoly", "svmLinear")
myFS<-fscaret(trainDF, testDF, myTimeLimit = 40, preprocessData=TRUE,
              Used.funcRegPred = 'glm', with.labels=TRUE,
              supress.output=FALSE, no.cores=2)

----Processing files:----
[1] "1in_default_REGControl_glm.RData"
[1] ""
[1] "Calculating error for model:"
[1] "1in_default_REGControl_glm.RData"
[1] ""

----Processing files:----
[1] "1in_default_REGControl_VarImp_glm.txt"
Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, rows, ncol(matrycaVarImp.RMSE), value = numeric(0)) : 
  replacement has length zero
```

When I choose any other model say svm the earlier error remains
ie:

```
Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) : 
  one node produced an error: incorrect number of dimensions
```

Am I missing something here? Could someone throw more light on this please?

Comment: Have you tried running it on only one core?

Comment: YES! I HAVE CHANGED THE no  of cores to 1 and checked and still the error remains!

Comment: It would be great if I could work on a small, reproducible example.

Comment: I have added the code and also the text file in my question in case u want to try it..

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you are trying to use `fscaret()` function in regression mode, but your data is obviously factorized (if not by you intentionally, than by `read.table()` or internally by `fscaret()` functions).
For the example you presented for `fsModels` only `glm` runs without NaN's for the code below:

```
titanicDF3 = read.table("combo.txt", header = TRUE)
View(titanicDF3)
require(caret)
require(fscaret)

    splitIndex <- createDataPartition(titanicDF3$Survived, p = .75, list = FALSE, times = 1)
    trainDF <- titanicDF3[ splitIndex,]
    testDF  <- titanicDF3[-splitIndex,]

    fsModels <- c("glm", "gbm", "treebag", "ridge", "lasso")

    myFS<-fscaret(trainDF, testDF, myTimeLimit = 40, preprocessData=TRUE, classPred = TRUE, regPred = FALSE,
                  Used.funcClassPred = fsModels, with.labels=TRUE,
                  supress.output=FALSE, no.cores=2)
```

Mark `Used.funcClassPred = fsModels`. Also note `classPred = TRUE, regPred = FALSE` which prevents fscaret() running in regression mode.